# Use the Lagrange multiplier method to find the maximum possible volume for a rectangular box inscribed in the ellipsoid $2x^2 + 3y^2+4z^2=12$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I know I have the correct value of $x, y, z$ but I get a different value for the volume.

My workings:

$$ f=xyz, g=2x^2+3y^2+4z^2-12, \psi=f+\lambda g $$

$$ \psi_x = yz+4\lambda x=0 $$
$$\psi_y = xz+6\lambda y=0 $$
$$\psi_z = xy+8\lambda z=0$$
$$2x^2+3y^2+4z^2=12$$

Solving the simultaneous equations gives,

$$ x=\sqrt2, y=\frac2{\sqrt3}, z=1$$

I know this bit is correct but when I try to calculate the volume my answer is incorrect

$$f(\sqrt2,\frac2{\sqrt3},1) =\frac{2\sqrt6}{3} $$

but they give the answer as
$$ \frac{16\sqrt6}{3} $$

which is clearly 8 times my answer

I did a similar question and once again I got the correct x,y,z but the volume was 8 times my answer, but I cant see why they are multiplying by 8

Comment: The length of the edges are $2x$, $2y$ and $2z$. Hence, the volume is $8xyz$.

Comment: How do you know the length of the edges are 2x, 2y and 2z?

Comment: The coordinates for the corners are $(\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)$

Comment: Draw a picture, the box is centred at $(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have for the volume ($V=xyz$) is the volume of the portion of the box in the first octant. But there are 8 octants, each symmetric to the first, so the volume should really be calculated as

$$V=8xyz$$

Updating your solution with the new objective function, it is clear that $x,y,z$ do not change--only the lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ will be 8 times its previous value.

Plugging in the $x,y,z$ you found, we get that the volume is $\frac{16\sqrt{6}}{3}$, as the given solutions indicate.

---

To help with the intuition surrounding this problem, we can reduce it to the 2D case. Consider the (poorly drawn) image below, and let $(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the upper right corner of the red box.

[image]

Then you have that the area of the red box is $A=xy$, but the acutal area of the insctibed rectangle is the orange box, given by $A=4xy$, doubling once for each dimension.

In the 3D case, there are 3 dimensions in which the volume needs to be doubled, but the concept is the same.